# How to use aritmatic using tapply() in R

Tags: r

I'm calling height, diameter and age from a csv file. I'm trying to calculate the volume of the tree using pi x h x r^2. In order to calculate the radius, I'm taking dbh and dividing it by 2. Then I get this error.

> Error in dbh/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
setwd("/Users/user/Desktop/")
treeg <- read.csv("treeg.csv",row.names=1)
head(treeg)

heights <- tapply(treeg$height.ft,treeg$forest, identity) 
ages    <- tapply(treeg$age,treeg$forest, identity)
dbh     <- tapply(treeg$dbh.in,treeg$forest, identity) 

radius  <- dbh / 2
```

In the vector dbh it is storing the diameter from he csv file in terms of forest which is the ID.

How can I divide dbh by 2, while still retaining format of each value being stored by its receptive ID (which is he forest ---> treeg$forest) and treeg is the dataframe that call the csv file.

```
> head(treeg)
  tree.ID forest habitat dbh.in height.ft age
1       1      4       5   14.6      71.4  55
2       1      4       5   12.4      61.4  45
3       1      4       5    8.8      40.1  35
4       1      4       5    7.0      28.6  25
5       1      4       5    4.0      19.6  15
6       2      4       5   20.0     103.4 107

str(dbh)
List of 9
 $ 1: num [1:36] 19.9 18.6 16.2 14.2 12.3 9.4 6.8 4.9 2.6 22 ...
 $ 2: num [1:60] 16.5 15.5 14.5 13.7 12.7 11.4 9.5 8 5.9 4.1 ...
 $ 3: num [1:50] 18.4 17.2 15.6 13.7 11.6 8.5 5.3 2.8 13.3 10.6 ...
 $ 4: num [1:81] 14.6 12.4 8.8 7 4 20 18.8 17 15.9 14 ...
 $ 5: num [1:153] 28 27.2 26.1 25 23.7 21.3 19 16.7 12.2 9.8 ...
 $ 6: num [1:22] 21.3 20.2 19.1 18 16.9 15.6 14.8 13.3 11.3 9.2 ...
 $ 7: num [1:63] 13.9 12.4 10.6 8.1 5.8 3.4 27 25.6 23 20.2 ...
 $ 8: num [1:27] 20.8 17.7 15.6 13.2 10.5 7.5 4.8 2.9 12.9 11.3 ...
 $ 9: num [1:50] 23.6 20.5 16.9 14.1 11.1 8 5.1 2.9 24.1 20.9 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 9
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `head(treeg)` and possibly `str(dbh)`? And more generally, I'd recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Shady... we aren't gonna do your homework man.

Comment: Using `identity` with `tapply` is pretty anomalous. Why are you doing it?

Comment: Who said this was homework. I'm asking to try help me to  understand how to fix an error. I'm not asking you to write a whole essay. Thanks coffeinjunky for the help.

Comment: Ninja edit alert.... it's homework based on the file path you edited to change. `setwd("/Users/user/Desktop/Assignment 3")`

Comment: Homework or not, it looks like a question about a particular programming error to me. I certainly agree that it is a poorly structured one, but why would we care what the motivation behind the programming attempt itself is?

Comment: cory,  Hey man, while programming I ran into an error, an error that has taken me hours to fix with no prevail. I decided to post my question here to see if anyone could help me understand were I'm going wrong. I didn't expect you to criticize me for asking for help. I'm not asking you to do my homework/project/assignment whatever you want to call it, I'm just asking for help. Thanks coffeinjunky for not judging.

Comment: You are gonna have to get a much thicker skin to survive this place...

Comment: Don't feed the trolls.

Comment: From `str(dbh)`, you see that this object is a `list` (look at where it says `List of 9`). You can't divide a list by 2, hence the error. Instead you need to access the values stored in that list. See corey's answer below for one approach on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to create a radius column that is `dbh.in` divided by two?

```
treeg <- read.table(textConnection("tree.ID forest habitat dbh.in height.ft age
1       1      4       5   14.6      71.4  55
2       1      4       5   12.4      61.4  45
3       1      4       5    8.8      40.1  35
4       1      4       5    7.0      28.6  25
5       1      4       5    4.0      19.6  15
6       2      4       5   20.0     103.4 107"), header=TRUE)

treeg$radius <- treeg$dbh.in / 2
```

Or do you need that dbh list for something...

```
dbh     <- tapply(treeg$dbh.in,treeg$forest, identity) 
> dbh
$`4`
[1] 14.6 12.4  8.8  7.0  4.0 20.0 

lapply(dbh, function(x)x/2)
List of 1
$ 4: num [1:6] 7.3 6.2 4.4 3.5 2 10
```